# GIT & GIT GUI not using SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, git-gui

In my Linux Debian, since last GitHub change, I can't push code into my repositories.

Previously I used user:pass authentication, but don't know how to do it using an ssh key.

I already set the ssh key into the GitHub site, modified the `gitconfig` file, but still asking for user/pass (`git` and `git-gui`)

Something is missing and don't know what else to do.

[image]

Comment: Your `.git/config` has the url starting `https://github.com`.  To use ssh, that needs to be `git@github.com`.

Comment: Or `ssh://git@github.com/…`